# Building OpenCV Mac OS X 10.8 (static)

Tags: macos, opencv

Build opencv static libs with:

```
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = OFF
build_opencv_core = ON
build_opencv_imgproc = ON
build_opencv_highgui = ON

WITH_FFMPEG = ON
WITH_PNG = ON
WITH_JASPER = ON
WITH_TIFF = ON
WITH_OPENEXR = ON
```

and other OFF

Libraries build is good

And now, I create new Qt project

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

In main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
QCoreApplication a(argc,argv);
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCam(0);

return a.exec();
}
```

But when I build my project I get next error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_cvCreateCameraCapture", referenced from:
_main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_cvCreateCameraCapture", referenced from:
_main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/ff/wbcdn98j5nx617_p5vpzq1cm0000gn/T//ccqFaXgY.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [TestCamera] Error 1
```

-

```
lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a
Architectures in the fat file: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a are: i386 x86_64
```

Comment: Help me. Please build opecv staticly (for i386 x86_64) and send me binary

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [brew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) to install opencv instead of building it manually or trying to use already built one. After you've installed brew take a look at `brew info opencv` for some additional info.

Or alternatively you can try to add your libraries to project with the full path. Like:

```
LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a
```

If there are some conflicts in your libs this approach will resolve them.